# heroku slug compilation error failed to read buildpack metadata: error in release script

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I edited some code and tried to push to heroku and all of a sudden received strange errors about slug compilation and now I can't push to heroku. I don't know what happened I didn't mess with anything out of the ordinary.

```
Slug compilation error: failed to read buildpack metadata: error in release script

   Asset precompilation completed (47.59s)
-----> Rails plugin injection
   Injecting rails_log_stdout
   Injecting rails3_serve_static_assets
-----> Discovering process types
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory

! Push failed: failed to read buildpack metadata: error in release script.
! If the problem persists, see http://help.heroku.com and provide ID 8e6d0ded-66b7-4696-a204-2a2f0fdf6e57.

To git@heroku.com:apollojive.git
! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:apollojive.git'
```

EDIT: Looks like this problem has been fixed. I was finally able to deploy

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**: Appears to be fixed. Or at least I was able to push an update without error.

I'm seeing this error as well, but only when pushing to my "prod" app - not "stage". I guess it's time to take a break and eat some dinner :)

Answer (score 1):

This has been resolved. It was an issue with a new release of the ruby buildpack and has since been resolved. You should be good to deploy to the platform now.

If you're still seeing this error, please do let us know by [opening a support ticket](https://help.heroku.com). Thanks!

Comment: I find it concerning that the status page never reflected this issue.

Comment: Understandable. The reason the status site was not updated was due to 1) apps in production were not affected at all, only the ability to deploy and 2) the issue was resolved before we even had a chance to update the status site.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it might have something to do with ruby version, since i was using 2.0.0-p0 (specified on Gemfile), and when I tried pushing I saw that it updated to a new version 2.0.0-p195, which has been recently released ( 14 may ).

There was this lines on Heroku log that suggested this:

Old: ruby 2.0.0p0 (2013-02-24 revision 39474) [x86_64-linux]
New: ruby 2.0.0p195 (2013-05-14 revision 40734) [x86_64-linux]

UPDATE:
I've changed ruby version on Gemfile to 1.9.3 ( did a bundle and commited Gemfiles ) and it works.